# How to configure a sublime file_regex for *.bas-files

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublime-build

I'm trying to configure a Build System for Freebasic files in Sublime Text3 and want to set the file_regex property to handle the error messages

```
{
"selector": "source.bas",
"cmd": ["fbc.exe", "$file"],
"file_regex": "..."
}
```

all i have is something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
"file_regex": "^[A-Za-z0-9\\\/:]*\\(.*)\(([0-9]*)\("
```

i want to parse this error messages:

```
C:\projekte\privat\freebasic\test.bas(24) error 3: Expected End-of-Line, found ...
C:\projekte\privat\freebasic\test.bas(25) error 41: Variable not declared, This ....
C:\projekte\privat\freebasic\test.bas(26) error 9: Expected expression, found ...
C:\projekte\privat\freebasic\test.bas(27) error 9: Expected expression, found ...
```

to make my question more precise. I have to fumble apart the filename with extension in a first group and the linenumber in the second group.

could you please help me to find the correct file_regex?!

Comment: i have tried the file_regex as described in the second code section `"file_regex": "^[A-Za-z0-9\\\/:]*\\(.*)\(([0-9]*)\("`

Comment: The `.*` is a greedy dot matching pattern, it may match much more than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

There were two errors in your regex :

\/ is not a valid escape sequence, the slash do not need to be escaped

the final escaped parenthesis was opening \( instead of closing \).
Try with this one :

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\\/:]*\\(.*)\(([0-9]*)\)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do:

```
^([a-zA-Z]:(?:\\[^\\]+)*)\((\d+)\) error
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mI1jN8/3):

[image]

*Explanation:*

- `^` - start of a line/string
- `([a-zA-Z]:(?:\\[^\\]+)*)` - Group 1 (filename):

  - `[a-zA-Z]:` - a letter followed with `:`
  - `(?:\\[^\\]+)*` - a literal backslash `\` followed with 1+ characters other than a `\`.
- `\(` - opening parenthesis
- `(\d+)` - 1+ digits (Group 2, line number)
- `\)` - a closing parenthesis
- `error` - matches a word "error" (to anchor the search)

**NOTE**: you might need to double escape `\` backslashes to make the pattern work (e.g. `^([a-zA-Z]:(?:\\\\[^\\\\]+)*)\\((\\d+)\\) error`).